# Noob enquiry regarding UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Right guys, I am fairly new to xcode and the iPhone SDK, but have kept on it over the last few weeks, getting there slowly, however I have just started building an app which uses the UIPickerView, so far I have a picker with 7 values. When a value is selected it is displayed within a label...Pretty simple stuff. But so far I cannot find any tutorials which cover how to load a standard UIImageView to which I can then exchange images depending on what is selected within the picker.(Mug shots of each person) Do you guys now anywhere I could find some help on this or point me in the right direction.....

So far my code is pretty standard:

in the .h file I have:-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Team : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSMutableArray *list;
    IBOutlet UILabel *pickerLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImage *pickerImage;
}
@end
```

and in the .m file I have:-

```
#import "Team.h"

@implementation Team

-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [list count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [list objectAtIndex:row];

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Selected %@", [list objectAtIndex:row]];
    pickerLabel.text = string;
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [list addObject:@"Doug Filder"];
    [list addObject:@"Chris Savage"];
    [list addObject:@"Nick Bennett"];
    [list addObject:@"Aimee Vacher"];
    [list addObject:@"Brandy Cardwell"];
    [list addObject:@"Jon West"];
    [list addObject:@"Dan Parsons"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an NSDictionary to store the name of the person and associate a file name, 
for example:

First of all, change that UIImage to an UIImageView:

```
@interface Team : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSMutableArray *list;
    NSMutableDictionary *filenames;
    IBOutlet UILabel *pickerLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *pickerImage;
}
@end
```

Then, here's how you load an image into it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [list addObject:@"Doug Filder"];
    [list addObject:@"Chris Savage"];
    [list addObject:@"Nick Bennett"];
    [list addObject:@"Aimee Vacher"];
    [list addObject:@"Brandy Cardwell"];
    [list addObject:@"Jon West"];
    [list addObject:@"Dan Parsons"];

    filenames = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [filenames setObject:@"DougFilder.jpg" forKey:@"Doug Filder"];
    [filenames setObject:@"ChrisSavage.jpg" forKey:@"Chris Savage"];
    [filenames setObject:@"NickBennett.jpg" forKey:@"Nick Bennett"];
    [filenames setObject:@"AimeeVacher.jpg" forKey:@"Aimee Vacher"];
    [filenames setObject:@"BrandyCardwell.jpg" forKey:@"Brandy Cardwell"];
    [filenames setObject:@"JonWest.jpg" forKey:@"Jon West"];
    [filenames setObject:@"DanParsons.jpg" forKey:@"Dan Parsons"];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [list objectAtIndex:row];

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Selected %@", [list objectAtIndex:row]];
    pickerLabel.text = string;

    NSString *filename = [filenames objectForKey:[list objectAtIndex:row]];
    [pickerImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You would have to use a array as dataSource. And an extra dictionary to turn those keys from the array into filenames. `[list allKeys]` will return an array with undefined order.

Comment: How would I implement this Matthias?

Comment: The code is right there. All you gotta do is replace the code in your methods with the corresponding methods in the example. Make sure you have your images in your project and to replace the filenames with the correct names for your files.

Comment: Im getting no errors which is good germain, but no images are being shown? Do I have to add a UIImageView into the xib file for these to be displayed?

Comment: Yep. Make sure your IBOutlet is linked to your property as well.

Comment: Sorry mate, im being a complete tool, must be the cold over here in the UK, im forgot to attached the outlet to the UIImageView on the xib, many thanks, you guys are the best....learning so much since join  here

Answer (score 1):

just replace this

```
  -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Selected %@", [list objectAtIndex:row]];
        pickerLabel.text = string;
        pickerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:string];
    }
```